Using an enum class as a key in a map when the keys have value duplicates
I have the following enum class:
enum class SomeEnum
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 2
};

Where some of the enumerations are assigned the same value (B, C). In spite of that, I still would like each enumeration to be unique aside from its assigned value. So, in addition to using the value of the enumeration for some purposes, I would also want to have the enumeration (as a unique name) added as a key to a map and assign it something else, e.g. add it to std::map<SomeEnum, vector<int>>
But this would not work - I guess the comparator of std::map sees SomeEnum::B and SomeEnum::C as the same key (because they both have value 2).
Is there a map that does have this feature of uniqueness, not doing a comparison of keys? Or how would I go about accomplishing this otherwise?

the problem is static_assert(SomeEnum::B == SomeEnum::C); , the compiler cannot differentiate between B and C , rewrite another enum without specifying their value, or wait for reflection in C++26

@3CxEZiVlQ No comparator could make this possible.

@steep Why would your enum have duplicate values if you want them to be uniquely identifiable? (maps require unique keys)

It's not possible for 2 to not equal 2.

@PepijnKramer Because it would be convenient for me to have their primary value (when I refer to them) as assigned by the enum, but would like to use those special "names" as keys to assign them other stuff (let's say, for secondary purposes). Now why can their primary value be duplicate? Because I use the enum for multiple purposes - each enumeration has a name and also a value - the name is unique, the value is not.

you can use boost enum to get a string representation of the enum values, then compare the string names instead ... which is slower and you need to add some boilerplate first ... and this boilerplate needs to be maintained.

I understand from your comments that my design is probably faulty here. How would you redesign this? Would you not use an enum when you want a long list of unique names that can have non-unique values? Would you use something else?

@AhmedAEK Well, a string representation I guess would not be ideal. Also I don't want to compromise speed here

Just a struct with two ints and a operator int() to convert to the primary one?

i'd probably start by inspecting the reason why you have duplicate values in your enum and whether it is worth keeping this uniqueness or storing the mapping externally.

C++ enums are namespaced integers, so your quest is ill-advised. The comment about reflection being able to distinguishable between 2 and 2 is just as farcical.

I would use a custom enum class (a usual case in pre C+11) instead of a built-in enum class.
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>

class SomeEnum {
 public:
  enum Vals { A = 1, B, C };
  using underlying_type = std::underlying_type_t<Vals>;

  SomeEnum(Vals val) : val_(val) {}

  explicit operator underlying_type() const {
    switch (val_) {
      case B:
      case C:
        return 2;
      default:
        return val_;
    }
  }

  bool operator<(const SomeEnum& other) const { return val_ < other.val_; }

 private:
  Vals val_;
};

int main() {
  std::map<SomeEnum, char> m;
  m[SomeEnum::A] = 'A';
  m[SomeEnum::C] = 'C';
  m[SomeEnum::B] = 'B';
  for (auto [k, v] : m)
    std::cout << static_cast<SomeEnum::underlying_type>(k) << ": " << v << '\n';
  m[SomeEnum::A] = 'a';
  m[SomeEnum::C] = 'c';
  m[SomeEnum::B] = 'b';
  for (auto [k, v] : m)
    std::cout << static_cast<SomeEnum::underlying_type>(k) << ": " << v << '\n';
}

Output:
1: A
2: B
2: C
1: a
2: b
2: c


you have an enum of distinct names that map to non-unique values, you want to separate the mapped value from enum value itself by creating a constexpr lookup table that maps the enum to its non-unique value, C++20 reduces the boilerplate a lot due by the using enum expression.
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

enum class SomeEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

namespace detail
{
    struct EnumRepresentation
    {
        SomeEnum enum_value;
        int corresponding_value;
    };

    using enum SomeEnum;
    constexpr detail::EnumRepresentation enum_map[]
    {
        {A, 1},
        {B, 2},
        {C, 2}
    };

    constexpr auto create_mapper()
    {
        std::array<int,std::size(enum_map)> mapper;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < std::size(enum_map); i++)
        {
            mapper[static_cast<size_t>(enum_map[i].enum_value)] = enum_map[i].corresponding_value;
        }
        return mapper;
    };

    constexpr auto mapper = create_mapper();
}

constexpr auto getValue(SomeEnum e)
{
    return detail::mapper[static_cast<size_t>(e)];
};

int main()
{
    // compile-time lookup!
    static_assert(getValue(SomeEnum::B) == getValue(SomeEnum::C));

    // distinct representation!
    std::map<SomeEnum, std::string> names;
    names[SomeEnum::A] = "";
    names[SomeEnum::B] = "";
    names[SomeEnum::C] = "";
    assert(names.size() == 3);
}

godbolt demo
the main disadvantages here are the extra syntax to map the values getValue(SomeEnum::B) and that someone might forget to map the values, which you can get around by using strongly-typed integers.
you could use X macros to remove duplication, and also make this viable with less boilerplate pre-C++20
#define SomeEnum_Values \
X(A, 1) \
X(B, 2) \
X(C, 2)

enum class SomeEnum
{
#define X(name, value) name,
SomeEnum_Values
#undef X
};

using enum SomeEnum;
constexpr detail::EnumRepresentation enum_map[]
{
#define X(name, value) {name, value},
SomeEnum_Values
#undef X
};
#undef SomeEnum_Values

your other option is to wait for C++26 reflection to offer a way to inspect the count and values of each value in the enum.
